# Graph of the function $\cos(x)\cos(x+2)-\cos^2(x+1)$ will be?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry, analytic-geometry

> Graph of the function $\cos(x)\cos(x+2)-\cos^2(x+1)$ will be?
>
> ```
> (A)A straight line (B)A parabola
> ```
>
> Give the corresponding equation too.

Source:JEE 1997.

Can someone suggest how should I proceed?Can't think of any way to reduce the the given equation to a straight line or a parabola's equation.Please guide me!

[JEE 1997 paper PDF version](http://www.metrohometuitions.com/admin/pdf/2CwfZX.pdf)

Comment: It's *obviously* not a parabola, so it's a straight line. The line then must have slope zero (same reasoning as in the first sentence), so it's the line $y = \cos(2) - \cos^2(1)$.

Comment: Why "obviously" ?Which "reasoning" ?

Comment: Draw a parabola. What's its behavior at $\pm \infty$? Or better: Is a parabola periodic?

Comment: Ok I agree it can't be a parabola.But still its not sufficient argument to say that it must be a straight line. @T.Bongers

Comment: Well, it's a multiple choice question and I've ruled out all the *other* options, so.... But if you'd like to, I'm sure that there's a long and painful solution at the end of some identities involving cosines of sums.

Comment: Use product to sum to convert $\cos(x+2)\cos(x)$, and double/half angle formula, it's a constant function.

Comment: @T.Bongers I would be glad to know that long and painful solution!Please tell me!

Comment: @frank000 Hey thanks :-)!Got it done just now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align*}
2\cos(x)\cos(x+2) - 2\cos^2(x+1) &= \cos(2x+2)+\cos(2) - (1+\cos(2(x+1)) \\
&= \cos(2) - 1
\end{align*}
Hence the graph is a  straight line parallel to the $x$ axis.

Answer (score 6):

Let $f(x)=\cos(x)\cos(x+2)-\cos^2(x+1)$

\begin{align}
f'(x)&=-\sin x\cos(x+2)-\cos x\sin(x+2)+2\cos(x+1)\sin(x+1)\\
&=-\sin(2x+2)+\sin(2x+2)\\
&=0
\end{align}

So it is a constant function, i.e., a horizontal straight line.

Answer (score 4):

I think the easiest approach is to evaluate your expression at $x=0,x=-1,x=-2$ and recall that three collinear points cannot lie on a parabola. Even easier: your expression is bounded for sure between $-2$ and $1$. Given the options, it has to be a line, and a horizontal one: the same conclusion also follows from noticing that your function is $2\pi$-periodic.

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos(x)=\cos(x+1-1)=\cos(x+1)\cos(1)+\sin(x+1)\sin(1)$$
we use the fact $\cos(-1)=\cos(1)$, hence $\cos(x)$ is a even function,
and we have too:
$$\cos(x+2)=\cos(x+1+1)=\cos(x+1)\cos(1)-\sin(x+1)\sin(1)$$
then
$$\cos(x)\cos(x+2)=\cos^{2}(x+1)\cos^{2}(1)-\sin^{2}(x+1)\sin^{2}(1)=$$ 
$$=\cos^{2}(x+1)\cos^{2}(1)-\sin^{2}(x+1)(1-\cos^{2}(1))=\cos^{2}(1)-\sin^{2}(x+1)$$
we now come back to the main formula
$$\cos(x)\cos(x+2)-\cos^{2}(x+1)=\cos^{2}(1)-\sin^{2}(x+1)-\cos^{2}(x+1)$$
$$=\cos^{2}(1)-1=-\sin^{2}(1)$$
finally
$$\cos(x)\cos(x+2)-\cos^{2}(x+1)=-\sin^{2}(1)$$